# Excel sum with "criterias"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to calculate the number of days pending/pended.

There are three days column. Date issued, Date approved and today().

How to calculate the number of days pended if there is a value on date approved so that excel will ignore the today() value?

If there is date approved use that if not use today.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Have you looked into `SumIf()` or `SumIfs()`? I'd start there, and read through "How to Ask", that @CharlieRB linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula to calculate pending days: `A2` is the `Date issued`, `B2` is empty if not approved or `Date approved`. There is no need for `Today` columns.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),TODAY()-A2,B2-A2)
```